# Use importhtml in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Sorry that I am not sure how to describe the question in the title.

I would like to obtain the data on the link
http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/pollutant-concentrations

There are 3 links which are 8 am reading, 12 pm Reading, and 4 pm Reading. What I want is the "4 pm reading". But when the page is open it goes to 8 am by default. So when I use importhtml below, I can only get the data of 8 am reading. Any one know how to get the data of "4 pm reading"?

```
=importhtml("http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/pollutant-concentrations";"table";2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=transpose(query(transpose(importhtml("http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/pollutant-concentrations";"table";2));"select Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12 where Col7='*4PM*' or Col7='*Time*'";0))
```